# How to read from a xml file and write it to another file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, file, xml-parsing

I am trying to read a xml file and write it to another file using python. I am using the bellow code:

```py
from xml.dom import minidom
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

main = ET.parse("main.xml")

root = minidom.Document()

root.appendChild(main.getroot())

xml_str = root.toprettyxml(indent ="\t")

with open("test.xml", "w") as f:
    f.write(xml_str)
```

But I am getting an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Sakib\python_freelancing\Richard\xml_merger.py", line 8, in <module>
    root.appendChild(main.getroot())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\xml\dom\minidom.py", line 1612, in appendChild
    if node.nodeType not in self._child_node_types:
AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'nodeType'
```

The xml file I am trying to write is this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<SERVERName >
  <Description type="string">LAMP Server</Description>
  <Destination value="string">"toprack"</Destination>
  <AccessLevel>
    <Rule name="terst"></Rule>
    <Rule name="RestrictionsSetup"></Rule>
  </AccessLevel>
  <Users>
    <user>
      <login>pelech 1</login>
      <password>passwords are saved outside</password>
      <type>pelech 1</type>
      <age>passwords are saved outside</age>
      <location>passwords are saved outside</location>
    </user>
  </Users>
</SERVERName>
```

Comment: You are mixing minidom and ElementTree and that does not work. `appendChild` cannot use an `Element` object as argument.

Comment: So how can I fix it?

Comment: Why not just create a copy of main.xml and name it test.xml? That seems to be what you want.

Comment: I want to do it programmatically.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile